# Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, sql, date

no logro guardar en mi db la fecha y la hora actual en una tabla tipo DateTime de SQL desde Java, mi programa es el siguiente:

```
public static void  Agregar(String fecha2) {

        String sql= "INSERT INTO fecha (hoy) values(?)";

        PreparedStatement st=Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
            Date d= new Date();
            DateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            String date = sd.format(d);

            Date fechaConHora = sd.parse(date);

            java.util.Date utilDate = fechaConHora;
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date (utilDate.getTime());

                st.setDate(1, date);

                System.out.println(date);





        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error al insertar datos:"+e.getMessage());

}
```

Quizas este errado con el codigo. Lo unico que puedo mostrar bien por Java es lo siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Date d= new Date();
    DateFormat asd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");


    System.out.println(asd.format(d));

}
```

Que es de la forma que quiero que se guarde en SQL, pero ahora directamente no guarda ni la fecha.

Comment: Estas usando SQLite, mySql, MSSQL, cual es el tipo definido en el campo "hoy", puedes agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: "hoy" es la tabla del db y esta en formato DateTime, uso sql en Xampp

Answer (score -1):

Te falta principalmente ejecutar la query con algo como `st.execute()`. Te recomiendo que le eches una ojeada a la documentación de la clase [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).